# find or recover deleted AWS glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have accidentally deleted an AWS Glue job but I don't remember which one. Can I check from some logs what job I deleted? and recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the job that you have deleted go to cloudtrail -> Event History -> Select Event name -> type in "`DeleteJob`" as shown in below screenshot.This will give you all the Glue jobs that you have deleted.

[image]

Once you get the job name then go to S3 -> `aws-glue-scripts-518038311791-<region>` ->   . Download this script and recreate Glue job using this script. If you are not using default S3 bucket for scripts then look for script in the bucket that you configured for your Glue jobs.